# Upower suddenly stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, usb, power-management, pop-os

It happened fairly recently, I started not seeing the battery/power indicator on the status bar.
I looked into `/var/log/syslog` and found the following error:

```
upower.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
systemd[1]: upower.service: Failed with result 'timeout'
systemd[1]: upower.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
upowerd[2559]: did not recognise USB path /sys/devices/platform/USBC000:00/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:001, please report
```

I'm using `Pop!_OS 20.04`, `5.11.0-7620-generic`  on Dell XPS 15 9570 laptop.
Also, I'm not sure if this is related I'm getting the following errors as well regarding USB:

```
kernel: [43298.572377] usb 1-12: device descriptor read/8, error -71
kernel: [43298.704740] usb 1-12: device descriptor read/8, error -71
kernel: [43298.812338] usb usb1-port12: unable to enumerate USB device
```

But whenever I try listing `lsusb -t` I'm not really seeing the offending device (usb bus 1 port 12).

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 10000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=, 12M
```

The curious thing as well is that whenever my laptop boots, I can't use external keyboards, mice, everything that's connected to the USB ports for at least 5 to 15 minutes. But I was able to use the keyboard prior to booting when I'm typing my password for the full disk encryption.
I feel like these two are related but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A month has passed, I basically gave up on this. I just accepted my fate.
I would boot up the laptop while I make coffee, maybe even have breakfast. When I get back, enough time has passed for all the peripherals to sort themselves out and I can use it normally.

But today is a different day. I opened Zoom, noticed that my webcam isn't working. I usually have an external camera that's why haven't noticed it. This gave me a hunch, boot the machine in BIOS, unchecked the Camera. Reboot.

It worked! No more errors, no more waiting for USB keyboards to work.

Apparently, my integrated webcam is the culprit.